# Getting UIElement from Storyboard in Completed event Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, animation, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have an Image that i'm animating with a Storyboard. I want to be able to change the source of the image after the storyboard animation has completed. However, I don't know how to access the Image in the Completed event handler. How can I gain access to the Image through a Storyboard object.

```
private void AnimateImage() {
    Image i = new Image();
    //Set name and source of image here
    i.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
    Duration d = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation();
    DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation();
    anim1.Duration = d;
    anim2.Duration = d;

    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Duration = d;
    sb.Children.Add(anim1);
    sb.Children.Add(anim2);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(anim1, i);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(anim2, i);

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim1, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim2, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");

    //Set anim1/anim2 To/From properties

    sb.Completed += StoryboardCompleted;
    sb.Begin();
}

private void StoryboardCompleted(object sender, object o) {
    Storyboard sb = (Storyboard) sender;
    //How can I gain access to the Image?
}
```

I'm doing this animation many times with multiple images so I cant simply make a member variable. I need to know which Image is done in the Completed event.

Comment: Why do you want to change the image after you finish your storyboard? If this is a simple animation using time as steps, you can do it completly in XAML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a Lambda expression for the event so you can pass in the Image as an argument

Example:

```
sb.Completed += (s,e) => StoryboardCompleted(sb, i);

 ....

private void StoryboardCompleted(Storyboard storyboard, Image image)
{

}
```

Comment: Fantasic! I guess I never thought about doing it that way. Thank you.